# Get application name in umbrella project

Tags: elixir

I have an umbrella project (`my_app`) like this:

`├── README.md
 ├── apps
 │   ├── app_one
 │   |     └── mix.exs
 │   ├── app_two
 |   |    └── mix.exs
 │   └── ...
 ├── config
 └── mix.exs`

I want to get the name of the currently running app,
for example:  `app_one` , `app_two`.
when i use:
`Mix.Project.get.project[:app]`
i always get the main project name `my_app` .
How can i do that?

Comment: By "currently running" you mean the application which owns the module you're writing the code in? E.g. any module in `app_one/**/*.ex` should return `:app_one`?

Comment: usually it will be the application which the module is in. but if for example, the module is located in a app that is just a library and is used by a different app, i would want to get the app using the library.(not the library itself)

Comment: What if `app_two` calls `app_one` which calls a library? Now `app_two` is using `app_one` and `app_one` is using the library.

Comment: I think i would want app_one. this is the app actually running (the app which is running the application.exs file)

Comment: As I would expect the application that currently runs to be the first to start up I suggest you give `:application.which_application |> List.first` a go which returns a tuple of three values. `{:app, 'app', '2.0.7'}`. Be aware though, that the application description and version are returned as charlist as we use Erlang functionality. I don't know if the starting order can be counted on in all circumstances. So far it was reliable for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can get the application to which the a module belongs to using `:application.get_application/1`. If you pass `__MODULE__` as the first argument, you'll get the application the current module belongs to.

```
$ cat apps/a/lib/a.ex
defmodule A do
  def hello do
    :application.get_application(__MODULE__)
  end
end
$ cat apps/b/lib/b.ex
defmodule B do
  def hello do
    :application.get_application(__MODULE__)
  end
end
$ iex -S mix
iex(1)> A.hello
{:ok, :a}
iex(2)> B.hello
{:ok, :b}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to Erlang's `:application.get_application/1` is `Application.get_application/1`. This returns `nil` if the module is not listed in any application spec.

```
iex> Application.get_application MyApp.ExistingModule
:my_app

iex> Application.get_application MyApp.NonExistingModule
nil
```